# Dynamically change ggplot depending on the arguments passed to a function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently writing a function which ultimately returns a ggplot. I would like to offer the user the option to change different aspects of that ggplot, such as the `xlab` by specifying it in the function. Right now I am using a code like this.

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- sample_n(diamonds,500)

plot_something <- function(data,x,y,x_axis_name=NULL){
  if(is.null(x_axis_name)){
    p<-ggplot(d,aes_string(x=x,y=y))+
      geom_point()
  } else{
    p<-ggplot(d,aes_string(x=x,y=y))+
      geom_point()+
      xlab(x_axis_name)
  }

  return(p)
}

plot_something(data=d, x="depth", y="price",x_axis_name = "random_name")
```

This works fine, but as you can see a lot of the code is duplicated, the only difference is the `xlab` argument. In this case it is not too bad, but my actual function is much more complicated and things get more difficult if I would also allow the user to for example modify the `ylab`.

So my question is, if there is a more elegant way to modify ggplots inside of a function depending on arguments passed by the user.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for the duplicated code. You could conditionally add layers to a base plot as desired like so:

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <- sample_n(diamonds, 500)

plot_something <- function(data, x, y, x_axis_name = NULL) {
  x_lab <- if (!is.null(x_axis_name)) xlab(x_axis_name)

  p <- ggplot(d, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    x_lab

  return(p)
}

plot_something(data = d, x = "depth", y = "price", x_axis_name = "random_name")
```

[image]

Or using `ggplot2`s built-in mechanisms to choose defaults you don't even need an `if` condition but could do:

```
plot_something <- function(data, x, y, x_axis_name = ggplot2::waiver()) {
  p <- ggplot(d, aes_string(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    xlab(x_axis_name)

  return(p)
}
```